# Conjugate symmetry Problem

Tags: matlab, fft, filters

I'm seeing something very curious in the Matlab code below.

```
X = fft(x);  
Xt = X;  
Xt( (end/2+1):end ) = 0;  
xr = 2 * real( ifft( Xt ) );  
Xr = fft(xr);
```

where x is a real zero mean sinus function sampled at Fs Hertz according to Nyquist.

The spectra X and Xr should be the same. However, Xr(Fs/2) is not equal to X(Fs/2). Also, xr and x are slightly deviating.

Am I missing somehting here?

Comment: They should be the same. Post the entire code (i.e. add the signal `x` you are using) so we can help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not handling DC and Nyquist correctly. These are both real and don't have a conjugate "partner" so you need to multiply them with .5 instead

Try

```
x = randn(1024,1);
X = fft(x);  
Xt = X;  
Xt( (end/2+2):end ) = 0;  
Xt( (end/2+1)) = 0.5*Xt( (end/2+1)); 
Xt( 1) = 0.5*Xt( 1); 

xr = 2 * real( ifft( Xt ) );  
Xr = fft(xr);
delta = abs(Xr-X).^2;
fprintf('Diff = %6.2f dB\n', 10*log10(mean(delta)/mean(X.*conj(X))));
```

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm. Could you provide any insight as to why   DC and Nyquist have to be multiplied by 0.5?